# TWC in Bridge, router forwarding ports, coming back closed?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, dvr

This is fricken maddening.  My client has TWC BusClass.  We've set their router to bridge mode with a static ip.  Works fine and I can ping the connected router, no problem.  The connected router is a remotely managed Cisco Meraki to which the NVR is connected.  NVR also has a static ip set.  HOWEVER - TWC was able to ping the forwarded ports on the router from his pc.  I can't see them as open.  Tried mac Network Utility and two different port scanning sites.  Always comes back closed.

Theories on where the screw up is happening?

Comment: Please keep the question to the point, include model numbers in use and IP schema. "TWC" or the client in the 4th line?

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, the problem was the gateway address on the NVR. It was set to 192.168.50.11 instead of 50.1

Crazy that none of the vendors I spoke to, most especially that of the NVR, managed to come up with the gateway theory. We new the data was getting to the router bc I could view it when on the local wifi. We therefore knew the required port was open. But everyone wanted to blame everyone else as to the reason the data wasn't remotely accessible.